# In android application- child browser is not working after upgrading Phonegap 2.1.0 to 2.2.0

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, childbrowser

I developed android mobile application using Android 2.2 and Phonegap 2.1.0 and i tested the application using Android 2.3.4 mobile, Application worked good.

In my application i am using child browser and push notification.

Later my colleague tested the application using Android 4.1.2 Mobile, he said "Geolocation not working", then he told me that after upgrading Phonegap to 2.2.0, problem solved.

so, i upgraded Phonegap from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0, but now i am getting error from child browser and push notification.

### Error in child browser

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addConstructor' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/resources/js/ChildBrowser.js:102

102 line : gap.addConstructor(function () { .....
```

### Error in push notification

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/resources/js/PushNotification.js:260

260 line : cordova.addConstructor(function () { ...
```

Comment: Make sure that you updated the js file as well as the jar file

Comment: where can i get updated js and jar files for child browser and push notification

Comment: It's my mistake, sorry for that disturbance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version of the ChildBrowser:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser/2.0.0

Comment: Thanks for the help, but not working, i got error in this line `cordova.exec(this._onEvent, this._onError, "ChildBrowser", "showWebPage", [url, options]);`

Comment: I saw you blogspot, thanks for the information about Cordova 2.3.0. when Cordova 2.3.0 will be released for developers ?.

Comment: It's my mistake, sorry for that disturbance

Comment: All I can say is 2.3.0 is coming soon.